# Can I perform Z-score values on percentages?

Tags: data-transformation, percentage

Can I perform Z-score values on percentages? It is correct? Or should I perform Z-values starting from frequencies?

I want to perform Z-score on percentages to 'declosed' my data, as, If I understood right, percentage are compositional data, so they are closed.

My raw data is a cross-tab, with 10 cases on the rows (X), and 8 variables in the columns (Y). Percentages are calculated for each row, and each one sum to 100%. It is right to perform Z-score on them, before running a cluster analysis?

Comment: Of course you can carry out these calculations.  Whether they are "correct" depends on what you will do with the results!  What purpose do you have in mind?

Comment: What do "vertical" and "horizontal" mean in this context? When you refer to rows and columns, could you show us how you are holding data?

Comment: Not clarified. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: You should really state the real problem you want to solve! cluster-analysis on ten cases doesnt look like a good idea.

Comment: Igorning any other possible issues, what you have is a "compositional data" problem. A search for that term will lead you to various methods used to deal with such data. Often some kind of log-contrast transform is made to move the data onto real space where "traditional" statistical methods can be employed as normal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data There is a very nice group in Girona Spain who focus on this kind of analysis and they run summer courses every year.

Comment: Thanks. I read about compositional data problem and log-contrast transformation, I will try to get more information. However, still nobody answered to my question... what about Z-score? It is an appropiate method or not? If not, why? Why log-contrast is a good method and Z-score not? Thank you to everybody answering.